# Latex algorithm standards

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

[image: What the code looks like[1]]

I have written some latex code for some pseudocode I written which uses:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

I was wondering whether there is a standard for algorithms in latex or just in general?

Should I be using that square root or sqrt(state), should I be accessing the array item by `state[i]` should I be using fractions or just a divide symbol?

Heres the code:

```
\makeatletter
    \def\BState{\State\hskip-\ALG@thistlm}
    \makeatother
    %this changes the style of the comments 

    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Manhattan Distance}\label{euclid}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Procedure{ManDist}{$state$}    \Comment{The current puzzle configuration }
            \State$total\gets 0$
            \State$puzzleLength\gets sizeOf(state)$
            \State$dimensions\gets \sqrt{puzzleLength}$
            \For{$i\gets 1, puzzleLength$}  \Comment{Loops through each tile of the puzzle}
                \State $tileValue\gets state[i]$
                \State $expectedRow\gets \dfrac{(tileValue -1)}{dimensions}$
                \State $expectedCol\gets (tileValue -1)\bmod dimensions$
                \State $rowNum \gets \dfrac{i}{dimensions}$
                \State $rowNum\gets i \bmod dimensions$
                \State $total\gets total \texttt{+} \mid{expectedRow-rowNum}\mid\texttt{+}\mid{expectedCol-colNum}\mid$
            \EndFor
            \State \textbf{return} $total$\Comment{The heuristic is the total}
            \EndProcedure
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There is no standard for pseudo algorithms. Yours looks fine. The answer to your questions is largely a matter of taste and aesthetics. Regarding spacing it might be better to use `/` or `div` instead of fractions, but as said, this is a matter of taste ...

Comment: Was just really looking for a little guidance I've been through the entire algorithmc documentation but there's no pseudocode which have any form of calculations in that I can reference to @gernot